# Unable to install Ubuntu. Cursor blinking on black screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I have burnt Ubuntu ISO to a USB. When I boot from it, my laptop shows a black screen with a cursor blinking on top-left. This cursor keeps blinking endlessly. I left it overnight once to confirm that it doesn't change. I tried installing Ubuntu in another laptop after this incident with same USB and I was successful in doing so. This blinking cursor appears as soon as I choose the pen drive from Boot Menu or if it is at the top in Boot Order in BIOS. I have tried both 32 and 64 bit versions. If I remove the pen drive and boot from hard drive, Windows boots up perfectly. I was able to burn Windows ISO to this USB and install it successfully.

What is the solution to this? The entire thing happens just after booting from USB (even before anything related to Ubuntu would show up).

Wubi is an option which I am trying currently but it is only a temporary fix as it supports only upto 30 GB hard drive. I want to completely remove Windows.

The Ubuntu version I have tried is 14.04 LTS (32 and 64 bits). I have tried booting from all USB Ports.

Laptop is HP Pavilion i5.

Comment: Did you use the same Live USB on the computer that didn't work as on the computer that did?

Comment: @NBCKLY Yes. Added this info in the question itself. Forgot earlier.

Comment: If newer HP with i5, it is UEFI. Wubi does not work on UEFI systems with gpt partitioning. But if you reinstalled Windows in BIOS mode, it converted to BIOS with MBR(msdos) partitioning and did it incorrectly. Post this from terminal in live installer if you can boot. `sudo parted -l` If you only get black screen http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Shows BIOS screens first, if UEFI you need grub menu and edit grub's linux line.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your BIOS is hawing trouble booting from USB.

Check if a new version of BIOS is available and upgrade it.

Or get somewhere a USB-SATA/ATA adapter and then:

a) connect to the laptop a DVD drive and try booting from it.

b) pull the hard drive from the laptop, connect it to some other PC and install Ubuntu there.